# Bootstrap 3 change collapse icon image on only the panel that is open?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Using Bootstrap 3 and cannot seem to get the collapse panel icon to only change on the collapse panel that is active / open....it is changing all the instances and not just the ONE active. Even if I use the class (this) and not #accordion it is still changing all the images.

codepen: https://codepen.io/mDDDD/pen/NWbdrGY

```js
$('.panel-group').on('shown.bs.collapse', function (e) {
      $(this).find('.collapse-icon').attr('src', '/img/minus-icon.svg');
    });

$('.panel-group').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function (e) {
      $(this).find('.collapse-icon').attr('src', '/img/plus-icon.svg');
    });


THIS FIXED THE ISSUE:
  $('.panel-collapse').on('shown.bs.collapse', function (e) {
      $(this).prev().find('.collapse-icon').attr('src', '/img/minus-icon.svg');
    });

    $('.panel-collapse').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function (e) {
      $(this).prev().find('.collapse-icon').attr('src', '/img/plus-icon.svg');
    });
```

```css
.panel-group .panel {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  max-width: 800px;
  width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.panel-heading {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;

  width: 100%;
  min-height: 98px;
  padding: 31px 15px 31px 81px;

  transition: 200ms all linear;

  border-radius: 0;
}

.panel-heading--blue {
  background-color: #20315b;
}

.panel-heading--blue:hover {
  background-color: #071842;
}

.panel-heading h3 {
  color: white;
}

.collapse-icon {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 36px;
  height: auto;
}

h3.panel-title {
  font-size: 19px;
}

a.collapse-link {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel-group font--dosis" id="accordion">
                                <!--panel one-->
                                <a class="collapse-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion"
                                    href="#collapseOne">
                                    <div class="panel">
                         
                                        <div class="panel-heading panel-heading--blue">
                                            <h3 class="panel-title font-weight--bold text-uppercase">
                                               Panel One
                                            </h3>
                                            <img class="collapse-icon collapse-icon--plus" src="/img/plus-icon.svg">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </a>

                                <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                                    <div class="panel-body">
                                        body
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <!-- panel two -->
                                <a class="collapse-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion"
                                    href="#collapseTwo">
                                    <div class="panel">
                                        <div class="panel-heading panel-heading--blue">
                                            <h3 class="panel-title font-weight--bold text-uppercase">
                                                Panel Two
                                            </h3>
                                            <img class="collapse-icon collapse-icon--plus" src="/img/plus-icon.svg">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                                <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                                    <div class="panel-body">
                                        body
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div><!-- /.panel-group -->
```

Comment: Fixed my own issue...was not using THIS properly or navigating the DOM properly. Question updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added an attribute called `iscollapse` to each image and it checks if the item is expanded or collapsed and change the icon accordingly.

```js
 $('.collapse-link').on('click', function (e) {
  if($(this).find('.collapse-icon').attr('iscollapse') == 'true'){
     $(this).find('.collapse-icon').attr('src', '/img/plus-icon.svg');
     $(this).find('.collapse-icon').attr('iscollapse', 'false');
  }
  else{
    $(this).find('.collapse-icon').attr('src', '/img/minus-icon.svg');
    $(this).find('.collapse-icon').attr('iscollapse', 'true');
   }
    });
```

```css
.panel-group .panel {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  max-width: 800px;
  width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.panel-heading {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;

  width: 100%;
  min-height: 98px;
  padding: 31px 15px 31px 81px;

  transition: 200ms all linear;

  border-radius: 0;
}

.panel-heading--blue {
  background-color: #20315b;
}

.panel-heading--blue:hover {
  background-color: #071842;
}

.panel-heading h3 {
  color: white;
}

.collapse-icon {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 36px;
  height: auto;
}

h3.panel-title {
  font-size: 19px;
}

a.collapse-link {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel-group font--dosis" id="accordion">
    <!--panel one-->
    <a class="collapse-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion"
        href="#collapseOne">
        <div class="panel">
 
            <div class="panel-heading panel-heading--blue">
                <h3 class="panel-title font-weight--bold text-uppercase">
                   Panel One
                </h3>
                <img class="collapse-icon collapse-icon--plus" src="/img/plus-icon.svg" iscollapse="false">
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>

    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
            body
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- panel two -->
    <a class="collapse-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion"
        href="#collapseTwo">
        <div class="panel">
            <div class="panel-heading panel-heading--blue">
                <h3 class="panel-title font-weight--bold text-uppercase">
                    Panel Two
                </h3>
                <img class="collapse-icon collapse-icon--plus" src="/img/plus-icon.svg" iscollapse="false">
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
            body
        </div>
    </div>
</div><!-- /.panel-group -->
```